# RequestFocus android application precedence

Tags: android, android-layout

Which button (back or next) would be focused on initially if I did the following?:

Focus on next in java code:

```
    protected void onResume() {
        this.next.setFocusable(true);
        this.next.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.next.requestFocus();
    }
```

Then focus on back in layout xml:

```
<Button android:textSize="10.0dip" 
        android:textColor="#ff000000" 
        android:id="@id/back" 
        android:layout_width="50.0dip" 
        android:layout_height="30.0dip" 
        android:text="@string/back" />
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        <requestFocus />
/>
```

Comment: Please ask your Question clearly...

Comment: @RajaMCA If i requestfocus for a next button in java then request focus for back button in layout XML then which one would be focused? Since two buttons cannot be focused at the same time.